# Change default .phtml extension to .php in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I use Microsoft WebMatrix as an HTML editor. Unfortunately, it doesn't recognize .phtml files used in Zend Framework by default. What can I do to change the default file extension to .php for all files in a project?

Comment: There is no way to add new templates? Horrible....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put something like:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->setView($view)
             ->setViewSuffix('php');
```

In your bootstrap. But there must be a way to tell your editor to use phtml its sad to have to change stuff just to acomodate a editor.

ps: not tested not close to a editor but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Even though running `zf create controller name` will, of course, still produce .phtml files, this is something I can live with it. And yes, changing file extensions just for the editor is a bit of an overkill, but it will save some time renaming the files every time you make a change. WebMatrix is a good editor, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to allow adding custom file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans for php is a good alternative. .phtml are fully supported. I am using netbeans for my ZF application since last 2-3 years. works like a charm!!

check this page https://netbeans.org/features/php/